# Smooth a plot with uneven intervals on x-axis

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, smoothing

How do I smooth a plot with my x-axis being dates of unequal interval. My data is;

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import plt
import datetime as dt

x = np.array([dt.date(2000, 11, 30), dt.date(2001, 3, 31), dt.date(2001, 11, 30),
                dt.date(2002, 3, 31), dt.date(2002, 11, 30), dt.date(2003, 3, 31),
                dt.date(2003, 11, 30), dt.date(2004, 3, 31), dt.date(2004, 11, 30),
                dt.date(2005, 3, 31), dt.date(2005, 11, 30), dt.date(2006, 3, 31),
                dt.date(2006, 11, 30), dt.date(2007, 3, 31), dt.date(2007, 11, 30),
                dt.date(2008, 3, 31), dt.date(2008, 11, 30), dt.date(2009, 3, 31),
                dt.date(2009, 11, 30), dt.date(2010, 3, 31), dt.date(2010, 11, 30),
                dt.date(2011, 3, 31), dt.date(2011, 11, 30), dt.date(2012, 3, 31),
                dt.date(2012, 11, 30), dt.date(2013, 3, 31), dt.date(2013,11, 30)])

    y = np.array([0, -2.15881, -1.18881, -2.91211,  -2.33211,   -5.06131, -4.24131, -6.04321,   -4.56321,   -6.42431,   -5.68431,   -8.83711,   -8.43711,   -11.02821,
                  -10.66821,    -12.90341,  -11.02341,  -13.77671,  -13.27671,  -13.89671,
                  -12.23671,    -13.89411,  -12.61411])

plt.plot(x, y)
```

I tried the `scipy spline` but had problem because of my uneven x intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me!

You have to convert the dates to numbers and use the **scipy.interplolate.spline** to make the plot smoother.

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import plt
import datetime as dt
from scipy.interpolate import spline
from matplotlib import dates

x = np.array([dt.date(2000, 11, 30), dt.date(2001, 3, 31), dt.date(2001, 11, 30),
                dt.date(2002, 3, 31), dt.date(2002, 11, 30), dt.date(2003, 3, 31),
                dt.date(2003, 11, 30), dt.date(2004, 3, 31), dt.date(2004, 11, 30),
                dt.date(2005, 3, 31), dt.date(2005, 11, 30), dt.date(2006, 3, 31),
                dt.date(2006, 11, 30), dt.date(2007, 3, 31), dt.date(2007, 11, 30),
                dt.date(2008, 3, 31), dt.date(2008, 11, 30), dt.date(2009, 3, 31),
                dt.date(2009, 11, 30), dt.date(2010, 3, 31), dt.date(2010, 11, 30),
                dt.date(2011, 3, 31), dt.date(2011, 11, 30)])

y = np.array([0, -2.15881, -1.18881, -2.91211,  -2.33211,   -5.06131, -4.24131, -6.04321,
               -4.56321,   -6.42431,   -5.68431, -8.83711,   -8.43711,   -11.02821,
               -10.66821,    -12.90341,  -11.02341,  -13.77671,  -13.27671,  -13.89671,
               -12.23671,    -13.89411,  -12.61411])

# create an array of numbers for the dates
x_dates = np.array([dates.date2num(i) for i in x])

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

# create more uniform intervals in x axis and use spline to interpolate data
x_smooth = np.linspace(x_dates.min(), x_dates.max(), 200)
y_smooth = spline(x_dates, y, x_smooth)

# creating a new date array from the new date number array
x_new = np.array([dates.num2date(i) for i in x_smooth])

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_new, y_smooth)
plt.show()
```

So, the initial figure is:[image: Original Figure]

The new figure is: [image: Interpolated figure]

And superimposing the two figures, we see that the match is pretty good!
[image: Superimposing both the plots]